# How to keep mysql names together in ordered list

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by, recordset

I have the following list of items

| Category | OrderNum |
| --- | --- |
| Prerequisites | 2 |
| NULL | 4 |
| Prerequisites | 6 |
| Sign Off | 8 |
| Sign Off | 10 |

I would like it to be ordered so that 'Prerequisites' is together and the NULL category appears after it, so that:

| Category | OrderNum |
| --- | --- |
| Prerequisites | 2 |
| Prerequisites | 6 |
| NULL | 4 |
| Sign Off | 8 |
| Sign Off | 10 |

Currently my SQL has the following order by:

`ORDER BY OrderNum <> '' DESC, OrderNum`

I've tried the following, however it puts NULL at the end.

`ORDER BY COALESCE(Category,'') <> '' DESC, OrderNum <> '' DESC, OrderNum`

I'm trying to achieve it so that the records with the same category are together in the recordset, the NULL item should appear before the 'Sign Off' category because the OrderNum of NULL is less than any of the 'Sign Off' records.

I'm not sure if that's possible in one query. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply all the conditions that you want with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN Category = 'Prerequisites' THEN 1
           WHEN Category IS NULL THEN 2
           ELSE 3
         END, 
         Category,
         OrderNum;
```

or, if there are also empty strings in `Category` which you want sorted with the `NULL`s:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN Category = 'Prerequisites' THEN 1
           WHEN COALESCE(Category, '') = '' THEN 2
           ELSE 3
         END, 
         Category,
         OrderNum;
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
ORDER BY Category = 'Prerequisites' DESC, 
         Category IS NULL DESC, -- or: COALESCE(Category, '') = '' DESC,
         Category,
         OrderNum;
```

But, if what you want is to sort the rows by the minimum `OrderNum` of each `Category` use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tablename t1
ORDER BY (SELECT MIN(t2.OrderNum) FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.Category = t1.Category),
         t1.OrderNum;
```

or, for MySql 8.0+ use `MIN()` window function:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
ORDER BY MIN(OrderNum) OVER (PARTITION BY Category),
         OrderNum;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=378470768995f9f6e52fd585f167d179).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `NULL` values right after `Prerequisites`, you can use `PrerequisitesZ` as the fallback for `NULL` values:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(Category, 'PrerequisitesZ') DESC, OrderNum;
```

Comment: It's very unlikely this will be a sufficient solution since this sounds like a general question concerning hundreds or even thousands of entries that might have hundreds of different categories, so such a hard coded COALESCE will not really have an effect.

Comment: @JonasMetzler based on "I would like it to be ordered so that 'Prerequisites' is together and the NULL category appears after it" isn't it a correct assumption that the OP wants it exactly after that category?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using two conditions in the `ORDER BY` clause:

1. if `Category` has the value "Prerequisites", it should come first
2. otherwise order by the `OrderNum` value

Here's how you would do it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
ORDER BY IF(Category='Prerequisites', 0, 1), 
         OrderNum
```

Demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7Pyddta1f96sJxYnQgZWam/0).

**Note**: Actually you can play how much you want with the conditions in the `ORDER BY` clause, as it can accept most of MySQL constructs.